# In the 1974 version of The Longest Yard, what was the reason for the drop kick?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-longest-yard

In the original, 1974 version of [The Longest Yard](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0071771/), during the big game, the convicts are on the 16 yard line facing fourth and four and Crewe calls for a drop kick.  The kick is successful (though if you watch closely the ball actually goes far left of the post) so the convicts get 3 points.

My question is: why attempt what was even at the time a pretty obsolete play instead of just kicking a field goal for the same amount of points?

Earlier in the game Crewe elected to run in an extra point attempt instead of kicking it, but he explained that was because they were showing off and intentionally trying to embarrass the guards.  However, since the drop kick play happened late in the fourth quarter while they were still losing, I would assume Crewe would be much more concerned about winning the game at that point instead of showing off.

Was there a rule in football back then that gave them some advantage to attempting a drop kick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, an advantages with a drop kick is that you have 10 blockers instead of the 9 you would have with a place kick, it also allowed Crewe to read the field before commiting to a kick (his opponents have nowhere near his experience or skill so he does not have to play at the same intensity he used to in the NFL where his opponents are some of the best in the world).

I am not sure any of these reasons are the real one though, my gut instinct is that the director wanted a drop goal because it looked cool and did not clutter the screen with more people and movement than was required.  It also kept the focus on Crewe.